# Entity Data Model not creating all relations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I created an Entity Data Model automatically from my database. There are 3 tables (`A`, `B`, `C`), and 2 foreign keys (`A 1-* B` and `B 1-* C`). The model that was created has all three tables, but only the second relation (called here an `association`). I am new to Entity framework and am just trying to follow a tutorial. What can be causing this?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your entity types.  Can you post some code?  The EF relies on naming and type conventions to create relationships unless you explicitly tell it how things should be set up, so it could be several things.

Comment: @JeremyTodd I know nothing of my entity type. I added an Entity Model and followed the wizard with all defaults. When I look at the database diagram, I see to FK. When I look at the Entity Model, there is only one.

Comment: Does each table have a primary key?

Comment: @kirsteng Yes. I would upload the table and index creation script or something if I could figure out how to get at it.

Comment: In Management Studio, right click database, tasks-> script database as -> Create to

Comment: @kirsteng I don't think I have Management Studio. I installed SqlServer with VS2010. It was part of the VS installer.

Comment: This is probably the right link.  If not look for 2012 version.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: @kirsteng It doesn't give me the tables, just a `CREATE` for the actual DB file.

Comment: what connection string is your app using? You will need to connect to that instance of SQL Server

Comment: @kirsteng Thank you. While preparing the DB schema dump for uploading (BTW, for reference, it is under `Tasks -> Generate script...`), I found that I had another (unique) index on the primary key field in table `A` (it was supposed to be on a different field). Fixing that solved this (I don't know why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was to double check the data structure truly was as you thought.  Once you had the correct data structure the model created as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you have your Primary keys set up in your related tables. I created an edm with entity framework version 6 in VS 2013 against SQL Server 2008 R2. The relationships were set up in the database but were not showing up in the EDM for a couple tables. Once I set the Primary key fields as Primary Keys in SQL Server, the EDM updated correctly.